# Word for the act of databasing

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Database has found its way into the English vernacular as a verb as well as a noun. I can have a database, but I can also database information.

I have heard used the other verb tenses 'databased' and 'databasing'. (Though they are still not popular) "I already databased that info". "The sever is still databasing that request"

My question is what would the noun be for the act of databasing or state of being databased? Databasation? Databasification?

I'm stumped as it's root base has no equivalent given it is always used without an object. Something can not be in the act of being based....

Comment: You want a word that means **"to store, modify, and extract information from a database."**?

Comment: **Database Management**, no?

Comment: I want a word that means "the act of storing a thing (noun) in a database". Similar to how verification is "the act of verifying a thing", exploration is "the act of exploring a thing", classification is "the act of classifying a thing", or exasperation is "the act of exasperating a thing".

For this has been causing me some exasperation.

Comment: I'm inclined to say that you need to go back to what you think *to database* actually means ... if you follow the logic, it would probably be *databasification*, but that's a neologism too far for my poor, bleeding ears. So I'd be looking back to the action to see where that leads - tabulation, manipulation, storage...

Comment: @Prof Yaffle Great point! In my specific case the root action would be **tabulation** since the action is transforming data to a tablular form. That said, I think I'll still use _databasification_ in my code, because neolgisms make me chuckle.  :p

Comment: I would not recommend using the verb form of *database*, and especially any derived form of the verb, in any sort of formal document.  Maybe (sadly) in another 10-20 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [gerund](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/gerunds/) form **databasing**, derived from the verb **database** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/databasing)

> *tr.v.* databased, databasing, databases
>   To put (data) into a database.

It's hard to find a better one, so consider databases as tables and we'll have:

**Tabulation**, a noun from the verb **tabulate** — [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tabulation)

> *tr.v.* tabulated, tabulating, tabulates
>   2 the act of putting into tabular form
>   *"the tabulation of the results"*

And the act of entering data can be termed **data entry**

Comment: How would one decide if the gerund was the correct form in the situation where the verb is applied to an object?

Most of the examples given can not be applied to an object (swim, dance, decide, dream).

Avoid' breaks that rule, but it also lacks a form for "the act of avoiding an object", Instead we use evasion, since evade is a synonym of avoid in that usage.

No synonym exists for database...

Comment: @LordofFailure See updated answer. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Excellent. It follows the general form of all the existing examples I can think of. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard "databasing" as a verb, and it's long, clunky, and confuses me.  I expect it to mean "the act of analyzing a real world entity relationship, and writing the DDL to implement a database".  "After the shopping cart is "databased", checkout can be "formed"" You sound like you are referring to the entry of a record or other atomic information.  Why not **entered** or **keyed** (if typed in)?

For a citation, the United States occupational classification authority has a job classification [data entry keyer](http://www.bls.gov/oes/current/oes439021.htm)